# psycopg2 linking error in Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, postgresql, python-2.7

I am just building psycopg2 module in Windows with Visual Studio.
I have installed visual studio for Python 2.7.
After compiling I am getting the linking error below:

```
Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\psycopg\_psycopg.lib and    
object build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\psycopg\
_psycopg.exp
pqpath.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQclear  
referenced in function _pq_raise
connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQclear
cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQclear
error_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQclear
pqpath.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQerrorMessage   
referenced in function _pq_raise
connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol   
_PQerrorMessage
```

Can anyone guide us how to build psycopg2 and pcrypto module in windows with visual studio ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy solution: download the prebuilt binaries from sites like [voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) (for pycrypto) or [UC Irvine's](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) or [Win Psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/). Harder solution - you will need to install the development libraries that `psycopg2` relies on, namely `libpq` from the [PostgreSQL source code](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/) and configure Visual Studio to include the path to the headers. I'm not sure what `pycrypto` needs for building from source.

Comment: Another thing - make sure the version of the libraries match your installation *including* I think the compiler. This is all a lot more common practice in the unix world than on Windows, but if you are comfortable.compiling then you can actually compile PostgreSQL itself quite simply too if you need to ensure version compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the information.. It will be great help...